# Getting this error constantly: IOUnserialize has detected a string that is not valid UTF-8

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

I'm getting these errors constantly from various processes, the invalid string is always the same though. How do I find where the string is located?

Here are the latest ones. I removed the duplicates.

```
3/27/14 04:57:51.705 SystemUIServer[331]: FIXME: IOUnserialize has detected a string that is not valid UTF-8, "~?�".
3/27/14 04:57:57.568 airportd[65]: FIXME: IOUnserialize has detected a string that is not valid UTF-8, "~?�".
3/27/14 04:57:57.685 configd[18]: FIXME: IOUnserialize has detected a string that is not valid UTF-8, "~?�".
3/27/14 04:57:57.698 Little Snitch Daemon[77]: FIXME: IOUnserialize has detected a string that is not valid UTF-8, "~?�".
3/27/14 04:58:47.176 com.apple.preference.network.remoteservice[12469]: FIXME: IOUnserialize has detected a string that is not valid UTF-8, "~?�".
3/27/14 04:59:35.939 CrashPlanService[75]: FIXME: IOUnserialize has detected a string that is not valid UTF-8, "~?�".
3/27/14 05:16:13.434 Finder[347]: FIXME: IOUnserialize has detected a string that is not valid UTF-8, "~?�".
```

Comment: I would uninstall little snitch and then reboot. Also, if you open console.app can you find a time before the messages started?

Comment: What type of Mac and which version of OS, please?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your Mavericks installation had a hick up.

Reinstall it.

To find out the source one has to open the pref files of all named processes and look for the UTF-8, "~?�"

You wont be able to fix it there but maybe see it.

You can try the search with Terminal `fgrep -iR "~?�" /Library/Preferences`

There is also a way to investigate the

> configd

You can debug configd by running another copy. You type in the terminal:

```
sudo /usr/libexec/configd -dv
```

It will ask for you password. This should give you debugging info about each bundle as it loads and dump any messages that normally go into the syslog to the terminal window.

You can load each bundle mentioned in your console log one at a time too e.g:

```
sudo /usr/libexec/configd -dv -t /System/Library/SystemConfiguration/Logger.bundle
```

Use ctrl-c to quit the process.

The number is the process id listed in the leftmost column in the Activity Monitor next to the process you want to close.

Looking at your console log, it looks like the common theme is Network. It might have to do with your airport app, but not sure since insufficient information given.

Does it comes up in Safe mode?